# How do you create or find a "userdata.img" file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am running the Hello World Android SDK test on Eclipse. After I installed the latest platform for Android SDK I tried to create an AVD.

In Eclipse:

> 1. Selected Window > AVD Manager.
> 2. Click New....
> 3. The Create New AVD dialog appears.
> 4. Type the name of the AVD, such as "my_avd".
> 5. Choose a target.(latest platform)
> 6. Ignore the rest of the fields.
> 7. Click Create AVD.

But when I returned to Eclipse I got a red error message saying:

`"unable to find a "userdata.img" file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.`

I have a windows vista 64 bit, Eclipse 3.7.2, and Android platform 4.0.3. If anyone could please help me, I really appreciate it. If you might have an idea of what I might be doing wrong I am all ears. :)

Here is what I have been trying to do http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 31):

Click on Android SDK manager in eclipse..
Then in Android 4.0.x your version.. click on ARM EABI v7A System Image.. and click on Install package..

It should work then...

Comment: since this has resolved your issue, why not tag it as the solution ?

Answer (score 6):

just for the record: i had the same error and couldn't solve the issue with the tipps here. in the end i found out, that i didn't made a choice in the CP/ABI dialog after creating a new device with the avd manager.. (this field was left open in a tutorial i found....)

Actually, Need to Android 4.0.x your version.. click on ARM EABI v7A System Image.. and click on Install package.. as per Raju.

After that I followed the advice of making sure that I filled out the CPU/ABI field and then all was good.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed "ARM EABI v7A System Image",still didn't work then try "android update avd -n h" in shell(h is the name of my android virtual device,repalce it with your specific avd name)